# Click in puppeteer not working inside ul tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, puppeteer

Below is the portion of html code of the webpage i am scraping using puppeteer. *The id's are starting with numericals.*

```
<div class="inner-menu">
   <ul class="module" style="float: left">
      <li id="0" class="moduleclass"><a class="active" href="/eu/alt/dashboard.htm">Home</a></li>
      <li id="4" class="moduleclass"><a class="" href="/eu/stu/studentBasicProfile.htm">Student</a></li>
      <li id="6" class="moduleclass"><a class="" href="/eu/exm/viewStudentExamDefinition.htm">Exam</a></li>

      <li id="7" class="moduleclass">
         <a class="" href="/eu/res/semesterGradeCardListing.htm">Result</a>
      </li>

   </ul>
</div>
```

I need to click on **li** with id **7**. I tried using the code

```
await page.waitForSelector("#\\37 ");
await page.click("#\\37 ");
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What's the idea behind `"#\\37 "`? Why not `"#7"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids that starts with digits are not valid and such selectors throw errors. But you can try XPath:

```js
const element = await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="7"]');
await element.click();
```